# How do I run a series of UNIX commands in batch file without terminating session?

Tags: batch-file

I have implemented automation through batch file to login into a remote server and run a series of commands therin. My batch file contents are as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO 1 -^> Connect 2 Server
ECHO 2 -^> Quit
SET /p ID=Enter Choice : 

IF "%ID%"=="1" start "" C:\work\putty.exe -load SessionName -l UserName -pw Password -m cmd.txt
IF "%ID%"=="2" exit
```

My cmd.txt file contains the following commands:

```
su superuser
password
ssh server
password
su MyID
password
```

The batch successfully connects to the server; but it fails to retain the session. Any tweak would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For my own use I verified what -m switch does for putty

> The -m option performs a similar function to the ‘Remote command’ box in the SSH panel of the PuTTY configuration box (see section 4.18.1). However, the -m option expects to be given a local file name, and it will read a command from that file.
>
> With some servers (particularly Unix systems), you can even put multiple lines in this file and execute more than one command in sequence, or a whole shell script; but this is arguably an abuse, and cannot be expected to work on all servers. In particular, it is known not to work with certain ‘embedded’ servers, such as Cisco routers.

Roughly what I guessed.  I think what's happening is that your commands might be running ok, but it terminates the session when done (which is also default behaviour for ssh [command] on unix.  To get around this you could try running 'bash' at the end to start a terminal as that user, which should stay running until you exit.  If this doesn't work you could try running 'sleep 10' to see if the session stays running longer - should verify that's the problem we're dealing with.

Much as stackoverflow demands strictly the answer to the question, which I hope I've provided above. I feel in this case it would be remiss to not flag the serious security concerns I'd have on what you're doing.  I would maintain that you shouldn't answer a question about doing something securely (with ssh and root passwords involved) without covering potential security pitfalls.

What you're doing seems like a bad idea because:

- it makes a file with two unencrypted root-capable passwords to anyone who finds that file
- this script is also giving *you* root access by default, which isn't a safe way to operate.  Ever accidentally type rm -r in the wrong window?
- Also, someone messing with your second hop (by say, replacing the ssh server with a script to run ssh but log passwords) would get the password to the third hop with root privileges.
- SSH keys should do away with using passwords to log on.  Use them.
- SSH port forwarding lets you also skip sshing from the second hop - instead just tunnel through it (I'm guessing the third box isn't internet accessible), again using ssh keys lets you skip passwords.
- the first 'su superuser' shouldn't be necessary unless your permissions don't allow you ssh (does an ssh_allow group exist on that box?), which might be the problem you should actually fix - not being a member of the group allowed to use SSH.